# python for Google Trends: "ValueError: year is out of range" when using interest_over_time

Tags: python, google-trends

I am new to using the pytrends module in python that allows to you pull data from Google Trends. This site gives a good introduction to the module: https://github.com/GeneralMills/pytrends

I am getting the message "ValueError: year is out of range" when using pytrend.interest_over_time(). Key parts of my code are:

```
import pytrends
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

google_username = "" #my username
google_password = "" #my password

pytrend = TrendReq(google_username, google_password, custom_useragent=None)

pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['Chipotle'], timeframe = 'today 5-y')
pytrend.interest_over_time()
```

I then get the error message "ValueError: year is out of range"

Comment: What's the full error?

Comment: Thats all it says. But looks to be something to do with:   --> 128         df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')   --> 276                         unit=unit, infer_datetime_format=infer_datetime_format)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i added `astype('int')` in request.py in line 180

from:

```
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'], unit='s')
```

to:

```
    df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'].astype('int'), unit='s')
```

(not sure why my line number is different, but looks like the same issue)

Answer (score 0):

Change the following in python...\Lib\site-packages\pytrends\request.py

**Line 3:**

```
from datetime import datetime
```

**Around Line 128:**

```
#df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'],unit='s')
df['date'] = df['time'].map(lambda d: datetime.fromtimestamp(int(d)))
```

This worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

As recommended in the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html) you can convert timestamps like this: `tstamp.to_datetime64().astype('O')`